# Is possible to use maven and npm in the same eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, npm

Is possible to use maven and npm in the same eclipse project?

I'm developing an web application using java with Spring Boot.

So, for java deps I want to use maven, and for the front-end I want to use NPM to manage the javascript deps like angular, bootstrap, angular modules, etc.

Is this possible?

I know that exists the WebJars distros, but they aren't up-to-dated so sometimes I use a webjars and sometimes I need to download the sources and attach to my project.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Example : JHipster (https://jhipster.github.io/)

Comment: Does this question really relates to Eclipse IDE or is this a more general Maven question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Maven plugin called [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) that will build NPM projects. You can build Java and NPM with that. Will that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a regular Maven Web project in Eclipse, and put the node and .js files into src/main/webapp. You should get both Maven and JavaScript natures on the project to do both Maven and Node.